# How can I change the text colour of ion-item

Tags: javascript, css, ionic-framework

I've been struggling to figure out how to change the text colour of ion-item.
This is wahat I have so far, i've found how to change the background colour.

```
<ion-item style="background-color: #82B1FF">
```

But how do I change the text colour?

Comment: Do you mean [`color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color)?

Comment: yes, sorry, I live in England. Trying to change the text color of ion-item

Comment: I mean the CSS `color` property, not the American English word. I know nothing about Ionic but that's what you use to set text colour. Please follow the link in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

CSS style for changing font-color is `color`.

So you can add:
`color: #fff;`
For a white font color, for example.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but <ion-item style="color: #2196F3"> didn't work

Answer (score 1):

```
<ion-item style="background-color: #82B1FF; color:#fff">hey
```

that's how you do that and those are the result: [image]

Comment: That's strange, I've tried this:<ion-item style="background-color: #2196F3; color: #E3F2FD">, but the text color is still the same.  I've even tried the color on it's own, but that didn't seem to work either for some reason

Comment: if that's only what you wrote it's easy...you need to add text or something so you'd be able to see some results like the "hey" I wrote in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using Ionic 1, the trick is to use the  tag to change the background colour, but then use a div class to inside the  to adjust the text colour.
Like so:

```
    <ion-item style="background-color: #2196F3; color: #E3F2FD">
      <div class="CustomColour">
        <h2><b>{{key}}</b></h2>
      </div>
    </ion-item>
```

And in the CSS file:

```
    div.CustomColour * {
       color: #E3F2FD !important;
    }
```